# Producer consumer pthreads program not finishing

Tags: c++, multithreading, unix, pthreads

So I have to make a program that uses 4 producer threads and 4 consumer threads, with an array that holds 10 random numbers at a time. Once that array is full, the producer must wait until those 10 numbers are consumed by the consumer, and then the consumer waits for the array to be full again. I have to do this with 1000 random numbers.

The problem is that the program never actually finishes, and I don't know why. I'm testing it out with 20 numbers, but the output is very scrambled and out of order, which isn't making this easier. I'll put the code and output below.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

// use 4 cons 4 prod
// instead of random number, use 1000 for all prod
// real time lib is optional
// Due thurs 11pm

using namespace std;

#define BSIZE 10
#define NUM_ITEMS 20
#define NUM_THREADS 8
#define NUM_PRODUCERS 4
#define NUM_CONSUMERS 4


int buf[BSIZE];
int nextin=0, nextout=0;

pthread_mutex_t lock;       // a shared lock veriale
pthread_cond_t empty, full;
bool isFull = false, isEmpty = false;
int bufCounter = 0;

void * producer(void *);    // function for producer thread
void * consumer(void *);    // function for consumer thread

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];      // array of thread IDs


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) 
{
    int i;

    pthread_cond_init(&full, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&empty, NULL);

    printf("\n **** Main Program creating threads **** \n");

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_PRODUCERS; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, producer, NULL); // Creating producers 
    for (i = NUM_PRODUCERS; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, consumer, NULL); // Creating consumers

    for ( i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    printf("\n *** main() reporting: all %d threads have terminated ***\n\n ", i);

    return 0; 

}  /* main */



void * producer(void * parm)
{
    int i, num;

    printf("\n ++++ Producer started ++++ \n");

    for(i=0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    { // produce items  

        num = rand() % 1000;

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);      // lock the buffer when adding num

        if (isFull == true)
            pthread_cond_wait(&empty, &lock);

        buf[nextin++] = num;

        nextin %= BSIZE;    // make the buffer circular
        bufCounter++; // Increment bufCounter

        if (bufCounter == BSIZE){
            isFull = true;
            isEmpty = false;
        }
        pthread_cond_signal(&full);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);    // get out the critical section 

    }


    printf("\n ++++ Producer exiting ++++\n");
    pthread_exit(0);
}    

void * consumer(void * parm)
{
    int i, num;

    printf("\n ==== Consumer started ==== \n");

    for(i=0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    {       
        // get item from the buffer and consume it

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);      // lock the buffer when removing item

        if (isEmpty == true)
            pthread_cond_wait(&full, &lock);

        num = buf[nextout++];
        nextout %= BSIZE;       // make the buffer circular
        bufCounter--;       

        printf(" Consuming item #[%d]: %d\n", i, num);

        if (bufCounter == 0){
            isEmpty = true;
            isFull = false;
        }   
        pthread_cond_signal(&empty);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);      // unlock the buffer and get out CS

    }


    printf("\n ==== Consumer exiting ====\n");
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

I really appreciate any help, and I know there's a lot of code here. Sorry.

EDIT: Here's the full output.

```
 **** Main Program creating threads ****

 ++++ Producer started ++++

 ++++ Producer started ++++

 ++++ Producer started ++++

 ++++ Producer started ++++

 ==== Consumer started ====
 Consuming item #[0]: 838
 Consuming item #[1]: 758
 Consuming item #[2]: 113
 Consuming item #[3]: 515

 ==== Consumer started ====
 Consuming item #[4]: 51
 Consuming item #[5]: 627

 ==== Consumer started ====

 ==== Consumer started ====
 Consuming item #[6]: 10
 Consuming item #[7]: 419
 Consuming item #[8]: 212
 Consuming item #[9]: 86
 Consuming item #[10]: 749
 Consuming item #[0]: 225
 Consuming item #[11]: 543
 Consuming item #[1]: 89
 Consuming item #[2]: 84
 Consuming item #[3]: 137
 Consuming item #[0]: 566
 Consuming item #[0]: 183
 Consuming item #[1]: 978
 Consuming item #[2]: 767
 Consuming item #[3]: 495
 Consuming item #[4]: 311
 Consuming item #[5]: 367
 Consuming item #[6]: 54
 Consuming item #[7]: 966
 Consuming item #[12]: 882
 Consuming item #[1]: 736
 Consuming item #[2]: 524
 Consuming item #[3]: 505
 Consuming item #[4]: 60
 Consuming item #[5]: 394
 Consuming item #[6]: 102
 Consuming item #[7]: 851
 Consuming item #[8]: 67
 Consuming item #[9]: 653
 Consuming item #[10]: 561
 Consuming item #[11]: 96

 ++++ Producer exiting ++++
 Consuming item #[8]: 31
 Consuming item #[9]: 754
 Consuming item #[10]: 188
 Consuming item #[11]: 85
 Consuming item #[12]: 143
 Consuming item #[13]: 967
 Consuming item #[14]: 145
 Consuming item #[15]: 406
 Consuming item #[16]: 165
 Consuming item #[17]: 403
 Consuming item #[4]: 562
 Consuming item #[5]: 628
 Consuming item #[13]: 920
 Consuming item #[14]: 834
 Consuming item #[15]: 803
 Consuming item #[16]: 444
 Consuming item #[6]: 962
 Consuming item #[7]: 318

 ++++ Producer exiting ++++
 Consuming item #[8]: 422
 Consuming item #[9]: 327
 Consuming item #[10]: 457
 Consuming item #[11]: 945
 Consuming item #[12]: 479
 Consuming item #[13]: 983
 Consuming item #[14]: 751
 Consuming item #[18]: 894

 ++++ Producer exiting ++++
 Consuming item #[19]: 670

 ==== Consumer exiting ====
 Consuming item #[15]: 259
 Consuming item #[16]: 248
 Consuming item #[17]: 353
 Consuming item #[18]: 757
 Consuming item #[17]: 629
 Consuming item #[18]: 306
 Consuming item #[19]: 606

 ==== Consumer exiting ====
 Consuming item #[12]: 990
 Consuming item #[13]: 738
 Consuming item #[14]: 516
 Consuming item #[15]: 414
 Consuming item #[16]: 262

 ++++ Producer exiting ++++
 Consuming item #[17]: 116
```

You can see that the program just stops and sits there, so I'm not sure if it's just done with all the numbers, but it gets called to wait again.

Comment: Copy-paste the output into the question itself. I refuse to go to the external site, that I am seeing for the first time.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius I added it to the post. It's just a Gyazo link, it's a program that lets you take a screenshot and then it uploads it to their site.

Comment: Never seen it - don't trust it. Copy-pasting is **always** easier than taking a screenshot, uploading it, and copy-pasting a link. Not to mention, that all information needs to be present in the question itself, and not in external sites.

Comment: Alright I just didn't want to flood the post with text

Comment: Text is best. Easier to parse and search than an image.

Comment: `void * consumer(void * parm)` and `void * producer(void * parm)` don't return. Program is invalid and all bets are off after that, so you might as well throw in a `return NULL;`.

Comment: Isn't that was pthread_exit(0) is for? This is going based off the demo my professor gave us.

Comment: Your program invokes undefined behaviour; the compiler is allowed to do anything it wants. The program is meaningless.

Comment: The consumer is supposed to find the max min and average for each set of 20 numbers out output it, so I guess that's the purpose. I just haven't added that yet because I can't get it working correctly. The purpose was to learn about synchronization among threads, but we pretty much had to self teach it. This is my first time seeing threads or ever using some of this syntax, so it's very hard for me to debug.

Comment: About that `rand()` call and the modulus, you may want to watch this: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Comment: Thanks for the info Jesper, unfortunately this is just the way I have to do it based off the rubric.

Comment: `pthread_exit` is a function call. It's not part of the C++ language so your compiler has no clue what it is or does. But a function with a return type must return on all paths. No exceptions. (Edit. Bad wording, that. There is an exception: [Exceptions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw)). This may not fix the problem you are hunting, but it will eliminate a problem. With or without  adding `return NULL;` I am unable to replicate your problem.

Comment: Unrelated: When you get a chance to work outside the rubric, look into C++'s threading libraries as well. Very useful and will result in more portable code. Not everyone speaks `pthread`, but if they are C++11 (or more recent) compliant, they speak `std::thread`.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: @user4581301 I added it in but I'm still getting the same thing.

Comment: @user4581301 `pthread_exit` doesn't return. There's no execution path that leads past it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (bufCounter == BSIZE){
        isFull = true;
        isEmpty = false;
    }
```

This is wrong. You jave just added an item to a buffer. The buffer is **unconditionally** non-empty.

```
    if (bufCounter == 0){
        isEmpty = true;
        isFull = false;
    }
```

Likewise, you've just removed an item from the buffer. It is unconditionally not full.

In both cases one of the assignments should be outside the `if`. OTOH there's no need to signal the condvar if the state didn't change, so `pthread_cond_signal` should be moved inside the `if`.

Lastly, if you are writing in C++, use C++ facilities. C++ supports multithreading now so there's no need to resort to OS-specific APIs.

[Here](https://ideone.com/S8h1Lf)'s the fixed program, minimally changed to make it a C program.

Comment: Thank you so much man, you're a life saver. It all makes so much more sense now.